# Using HTTPRequest "Method"->"PUT" with photos in AWS S3

Tags: storage, amazon-web-services, http-functions

I'm able to post strings (text files) to AWS S3 using REST API's, but I can't post photos/files.

Because the "content-length" or `ByteCount` of a Wolfram Language expression is larger than the actual photo or data, I'm importing the photo with "Byte":

```
mContent = Import[aPath, "Byte"];
mByteLength = Length[mContent];
```

When I generate my Hash for `mContent` and try to "PUT" it like this:

```
URLExecute[HTTPRequest["http://myBucket.s3.amazonaws.com", <|Method->"PUT","Headers"->mHeader,
"Body"->mContent]
```

where `mHeader` is a complex AWS header, I get the error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>XAmzContentSHA256Mismatch</Code><Message>The provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header does not match what was computed.</Message
<ClientComputedContentSHA256>a440d87eb4b5da1b8decf760ad3f8350bae7a83ccfcdd2eda029f3dde51b663a</ClientComputedContentSHA256
<S3ComputedContentSHA256>e2bae210a3ee03a2d2987d63639a17d5206e7660fe758cc17ecb4fc7137c9010</S3ComputedContentSHA256><RequestId>44B77755E6F6BC81</RequestId>
<HostId>Jd8MRLSYntEaguxJPJ/dbt+Ri4aZjk7etQp/O+dK6+XehJQ2sFF3lABDlciGBBGyRFuOSg0dzAo=</HostId></Error>
```

---

**Example of mHeader**

Here's the header I'm using. Not sure how helpful this is:

```
<|"X-Amz-Content-SHA256" -> "a440d87eb4b5da1b8decf760ad3f8350bae7a83ccfcdd2eda029f3dde51b663a",
"content-length" -> 82384, "content-type" -> "image/jpeg", 
"X-Amz-Date" -> "20190321T035330Z", 
"Host" -> "myBucket.s3.amazonaws.com", 
"Authorization" -> "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
    Credential=***publicKey***/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request,
    SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,
    Signature=3ac3e35626c32c011eaAUTHORIZATION-HASH"|>
```

---

**Additional information**

I tried changing the "Body" specification, but I can't figure out exactly what to do. Here's another example:

```
URLExecute[HTTPRequest["https://mybucket.s3.amazonawx.com", <|Method -> "PUT", "Headers" -> mHeader,
    "Body" -> {"image" -> <|"MIMEType" -> "image/jpeg", "Content"->File[aPath]|>}|>]
```

This results in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request \
signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. \
Check your key and signing \
method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>*******public key*******</AWSAccessKeyId>\
<StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20190321T033955Z
20190321/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request
f26d4ff70df95f868dd54f9496ad211255a909e59d1386814549aece5c823a8f</\
StringToSign><SignatureProvided>\
cbeaff51f2459efff00c39b15d953b90f5270662b6e36d9f94cd9ab9f7217aa5</\
SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 \
48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 31 39 30 33 32 31 54 30 33 33 39 35 35 5a 0a \
...morebytes...
61 39 30 39 65 35 39 64 31 33 38 36 38 31 34 35 34 39 61 65 63 65 35 \
63 38 32 33 61 38 66</StringToSignBytes><CanonicalRequest>PUT
/test.jpeg

content-length:82384
content-type:image/jpeg; \
boundary=------------------------13896c956eada0be
host:afslabdb.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:\
a440d87eb4b5da1b8decf760ad3f8350bae7a83ccfcdd2eda029f3dde51b663a
x-amz-date:20190321T033955Z

content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
a440d87eb4b5da1b8decf760ad3f8350bae7a83ccfcdd2eda029f3dde51b663a</\
CanonicalRequest><CanonicalRequestBytes>50 55 54 0a 2f 74 65 73 74 2e \
6a 70 65 67 0a 0a 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 6c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a 38 32 \
...lots of bytes...
62 61 65 37 61 38 33 63 63 66 63 64 64 32 65 64 61 30 32 39 66 33 64 \
64 65 35 31 62 36 36 33 \
61</CanonicalRequestBytes><RequestId>4D0FBF28400578D9</RequestId><\
HostId>X7HAdHvlQlUQy6d4v2gC7uzh7rdJ3aFfUZL8xSby9Ecw3ep+cG/\
1Zfv2mskN9kEr9/S3SXlXFwI=</HostId></Error>
```

The documentation for HTTPRequest isn't quite as thorough as I think I need, so I'd appreciate some help from Wolfram Language experts/developers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with my content hash not matching the AWS calculated hash (as you can see in the response from AWS). I didn't figure out how to get them to match, but I found an option in the AWS documentation to use `UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD`. So instead of calculating a content hash for the key `x-aws-content-sha256`, simply assign the value of that key to the literal `"UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD"`.

Everything else is hashed and authorized, so there isn't a major security issue here.

After using `UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD` my file went straight to S3 using

```
<|Method -> "PUT", "Headers" -> mHeader, "Body" -> mContent|>
```

as the association in the `HTTPRequest`. `mContent` here is `Import[myFile,"Byte"]` and the header is similar to the one given in the example above but with `"UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD"` used for the content hash (`x-amz-content-sha256`).